# How to implement Docker Wormhole Pattern on Gitlab CI

Tags: java, spring, docker, gitlab-ci, testcontainers

I'm trying to run TestContainers on a Spring-Boot aplication, the job in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` is simple and I don't want to use a docker-in-docker image to do the job. How can I reuse the maven image with a [Docker Wormhole Pattern](https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/dind_patterns/)?

```
test backend:
  stage: test
  image: maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-alpine
  script:
    - mvn clean test
```

Note: I don't have a Dockerfile, the app is pretty simple.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-socket-binding

Comment: I will take a look, thank you!